# Can I pass a string array from view to viewmodel using MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a scenario where I want to be able to collect an array of strings in the UI...  The viewmodel shouldn't care how the strings are collected...  And pass that array of strings to the viewmodel.

Is there a WPF control that can bind to an array of strings that doesn't require it being an itemsSource?

I want the viewmodel to be able to process the array as a whole.  This seems like it should be a simple thing, but I'm just not finding a solution.  I was considering using a textbox and just delimiting the strings and breaking it apart in the viewmodel.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

J

Comment: What about `ItemsSource` is troubling you?  A simple `ItemsControl` bound to an observable array of strings with a text box in the item template would work.  Just have an Add (and maybe Delete) button bound to a command that manipulates the observable array.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to pass an array to the viewmodel to then be processed? In this case you may not want to bind it to a property, but pass it as a parameter of a command.

Comment: I want the array to be passed as a unit, not individually as they are added to an ItemsControl.  In some cases (drag and drop) there isn't, necessarily, a command attached to the trigger.  I want to respond with a different UI if it's one item as opposed to several.

Comment: if you are using the `MvvM` then your colelction is already in your view model, Binding takes care of displaying the items. It looks like you are not using Binding here. How do you populate the list of Items in UI?

Comment: @XAMlMAX, I would use a binding if I could figure out how to bind to a string array as an atomic object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a solution with working `Binding` and a `string[]`.
Main window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="SO_app.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VM;assembly=VM"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SO_app"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Now the ViewModel (base):

```
namespace VM
{
    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now the Main View Model:

```
namespace VM
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Items = new string[10];
            Items[0] = "First string";
            Items[1] = "Second string";
        }

        private string[] _items;

        public string[] Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
            set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged("Items"); }
        }
    }
}
```

This way your `Binding` will work and you will have access to the collection iun your View Model.
If you need any more help with this let us know.
**Assumptions**

1. You can use references within a solution and assign them.
2. You have working understanding of `Binding`.

Happy coding

Comment: In this scenario, the setter would get called as each item is added to the listbox, wouldn't it?  I want to be able to assign an entire array as an atomic assignment, so that the viewmodel only gets triggered when the entire array is assigned.

Comment: @DigitalCamel And what stops you from creating a button when the array is complete/full to process it?